# Show thumbnails in Mac terminal?

Tags: mac, terminal, ls, thumbnails

Some time ago I've googled nice screenshot of Mac terminal

[image]

How it can be possible? Special terminal application or special settings of `ls`?

Comment: That looks like a Linux terminal window that just happens to be running on Apple hardware. This is likely not possible with the built-in OS X Terminal application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a terminal emulator running on a Linux machine `ssh`d into an OS X box. E.g.: [terminology](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/terminology-more-than-terminal-emulator.html)

Answer (score 1):

### This is not possible with the native Terminal app on Apple OS X.

Your screenshot looks like it is from an Ubuntu box running gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It's `ubuntu`, not `Mac OS`. Didn't you see the terminal background color? It's default terminal background color of ubuntu.

He just changed the hostname by command `hostname dennis-MacBookPro`.

Nice prank!

Comment: Not necessarily. You could still be logged into an OS X machine via SSH.

Comment: or you could match the background color to match Ubuntu. What gives it away is the window decorations, which don't match macOS window manager. An as @slhck says, it's more likely that the user is logged into a mac box than trying to prank anyone